# Haskell map with keys from different types

Tags: haskell, types

I have some types

```
data Foo = Foo
data Bar = Bar 
data Baz = Baz
```

I want to use them as keys for a Map. Is this possible, and if so, how?

Additonal context below:

I have an application that builds VMs. I have seperated the work into Phases. Currently I have this type

```
data CurrentPhase = PHASEONE
                  | PHASETWO
                  | PHASETHREE (deriving Eq,Ord)
```

So far so good right, no problems like what I mentioned above. However, I made a type class to describe operations that are phase specific

```
class PhaseOps phase where
  preValidate :: JobID -> phase -> Handler (Status)
  doPreProc :: JobID -> phase -> Handler (Status)
  updateConfig :: JobID -> phase -> Handler ()
  postValidate :: JobID -> phase -> Handler (Status)
```

in order for this to work, I had to create a new set of singleton data types to use for `PhaseOps` instances.

`data PhaseOne = PhaseOne`

.. and so on

now I have these singleton types, and `CurrentPhase`. I'd like to get rid of `CurrentPhase` (which I am using for a Map with `CurrentPhase` being the key), and use my singleton data types.

Comment: Is there a problem with `data FooBarBaz = Foo | Bar | Baz`? (Specifically, why doesn't this work?)

Comment: What would be the type of (the keys of) that map?

Comment: Yeah I need these to be seperate types.

Comment: @delnan : That's the problem. Is there some type trickery such that I can have a type that could refer to Foo Bar or Baz? If so, then the type of the key would be that.

Comment: dbaupp: It doesn't work because it doesn't fit the requirements I need. I'm trying to leave out what I percieved to be superfluous information.

Comment: There is a problem with storing different type keys in a single map, I mean how will you compare two values of different types ? The best you can do is create a union of Maps for each type and use type classes (or type families) to write your own wrappers around it.

Comment: I begining to think that a Map is the wrong data structure to use.

Comment: Michael: What information are you trying to leave out? What is your larger goal for this program? There is likely a better way to do it than making a map that takes different types, which I'm not even sure is possible, for the reasons Mystic notes.

Comment: @Mystic  That's not entirely true. While it isn't good for a Haskell beginner to try, there are uses of Data.Dynamic to create maps using various types as keys - the kdtree package does (or did) do exactly this.

Comment: @MichaelLitchard: Well, if you simply told us what problem you're trying to solve we could tell you if that was the case. Don't ask for helps to complete a step, ask for help to reach a goal. Sometimes the steps you're trying to take to the goal are only wrong and misleading. (And sometimes not, but why chance it?)

Comment: I have a habit of putting in too much information, so now I try to strip it down to essentials. Of course, the entire approach may be wrong, or something I don't think is important really is. Anyway I updated, is that sufficient context?

Comment: I note that `PhaseOps` looks a great deal like a class that wants to be a record of functions instead.

Comment: @C.A McCann, I believe you are right. I picked type class for the wrong reasons. Time for a re-design.

Comment: Still context is not very clear .. What do you want Map for ? Do you want a function from singleton phases to CurrentPhase .. ?

Comment: @Mystic - I want the Map to track information that phase needs to execute correctly, a way to track errors, and the results of a successful execution of a phase. I wanted a Map instead of List because in the event I needed to start a VM build at an aribtrary phase, it seemed using a Map would be the easiest way to assess the configuration information for any given phase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The straightforward solution is to use keys of type `Either Foo (Either Bar Baz)`. This gets verbose quickly as you add possible types and is a bit ugly anyway, so it often makes more sense to use a special-purpose equivalent such as:

```
data FooBarBaz = FooVal Foo | BarVal Bar | BazVal Baz
```

This is similar to combining them into one type directly, but trades off a bit more verbosity in the combined type for being able to still use the individual types elsewhere. This is a relatively common pattern; for instance, I've seen it often in types representing syntax trees, where a "top level declaration" type might take this form, with each kind of declaration being its own separate type.

Depending on the nature of your problem there might be other approaches that would be better, but the above is the only good general-purpose solution I can think of--if you don't like doing it this way, you'll need to more clearly specify *why* and elaborate somewhat on what you need these types to accomplish.

---

*Edit in response to clarification:*

As I mentioned in the comments on the question, `PhaseOps` looks a great deal like a class that wants to be a record of functions instead. Furthermore, if you have such a class, wanting a way to work with multiple instance types as if they were a single type is a very strong indication that it's time to step back and rethink your design.

Continuing with such a design almost always leads to either mucking about with `Typeable`, as Thomas M. DuBuisson mentions in the comments, or to mucking about with existential types (which is a well-known anti-pattern these days). It's true that such approaches are *occasionally* required, but are best avoided unless you can very clearly explain (even if only to yourself) why you need them. Otherwise, they create far more problems than they solve.

Incidentally, if you want to retain some of the benefits of separate types, I'd consider using your singleton types for phantom type tagging and/or hiding the constructor for the `PhaseOps` record and using a smart constructor that takes a `CurrentPhase` argument.

Comment: @MichaelLitchard: Edited the answer to match the comment. :]